# Where can I create and order custom IR remote covers like this?

Tags: remote-control

I recently bought a standard IR remote for my Arduino project:

[image]

You can peel off that entire remote cover, revealing the circuitry and the button touch points - I’d like to know of a place where I’m able to create my own custom remote cover for my project, so I can use my own button labels/colours.

Does such a place exist? These styles of remotes are very common, and I have several in my home (for Stereos, HDMI splitters etc) so I would’ve thought you could create and order them somewhere.

Comment: Maybe you can 3d print them?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ask a shop where they print advertising to stick on windows and vehicles, custom posters, vinyl cutouts, etc.
I guess your cover was printed flat and was soft enough to curve over each button of the remote.